# How to implement arguments into custom commands - Minecraft Forge 1.16.5

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to implement simple SetHome and Home commands into my mod using the Forge 1.16.5 MDK. I followed TutorialsByKaupenjoe's custom commands video (https://youtu.be/bYH2i-KOLgk) but they didn't describe the use of arguments in commands. I have found very brief and limited descriptions on how to use argument types and even looked at the vanilla commands. The best resource I could find was (https://github.com/TheGreyGhost/MinecraftByExample/blob/master/src/main/java/minecraftbyexample/mbe45_commands/MBEquoteCommand.java).

this is my SetHomeCommand.java class

```
package net.caret.goggleutils.commands;

import com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher;
import com.mojang.brigadier.arguments.IntegerArgumentType;
import com.mojang.brigadier.exceptions.CommandSyntaxException;
import net.caret.goggleutils.GoggleUtils;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandSource;
import net.minecraft.command.Commands;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.ServerPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.text.StringTextComponent;

public class SetHomeCommand {
    public SetHomeCommand(CommandDispatcher<CommandSource> dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.register(
                Commands.literal("sethome")
                .then(Commands.argument("number", IntegerArgumentType.integer(1, 10)))
                        .executes(commandContext -> setHome(commandContext.getSource(), IntegerArgumentType.getInteger(commandContext, "number")))
        );
    }

    private int setHome(CommandSource source, int number) throws CommandSyntaxException{
        System.out.println("test");
        ServerPlayerEntity player = source.asPlayer();
        BlockPos playerPos = player.getPosition();
        String pos = "(" + playerPos.getX() + ", " + playerPos.getY() + "," + playerPos.getZ() + ")";

        player.getPersistentData().putIntArray(GoggleUtils.MODID + String.valueOf(number) + "home", new int[]{playerPos.getX(), playerPos.getY(), playerPos.getZ()});

        source.sendFeedback(new StringTextComponent("Set home at " + pos), true);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Everything runs properly (I have also subscribed to the RegisterCommandsEvent in another class) and the game autocompletes as it should, but when I try `/sethome 1` I get

```
Unknown or incomplete command, see below for error
/sethome 1<--[HERE]
```

This seems to be a problem with the builder chain (as the console does not print "test").

Comment: Are you sure to have enough permission ? And to declare command ?

Comment: do you have to have OP permissions? Edit: I tried with OP permissions and it gives me the same error

Comment: Ok, and you well declare the command such as written at the end of the video that you gave ?

Comment: Yes it is declared in a ModEvents.java class

Comment: With all others command, and all others are working ? And if you do only `/sethome` does it works ?

Comment: No it doesn't work when I only do /sethome, I deviated from the video to be able to add multiple homes and not just one. I tried doing just /sethome and the game said: `An unexpected error occurred trying to execute that command` and the console still doesn't print "text"

Comment: Ok, I suggest you to make less things until it doesn't works. I mean don't try to do the perfect thing for your command. And sorry, I never made forge dev, only lot of bukkit/spigot dev so I can help you but not so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you place the .execute() outside the .then(Commands.argument(...))

The correct part of code will be:

```
.then(Commands.argument("number", IntegerArgumentType.integer(1, 10))
                    .executes(commandContext -> setHome(commandContext.getSource(), IntegerArgumentType.getInteger(commandContext, "number")))
    ));
```

Also, if you have the last Forge 1.16.5 MDK, some of the code in the method setHome could be outdated. Ej:

- 'source.asPlayer()' in new versions will be 'source.getPlayerOrException()'
- 'source.sendFeedback() will be 'source.sendSuccess()'

Comment: Thank you, placing the .executes() inside the .then statement worked! But source.getPlayerOrException does not exist on the latest 1.16.5 MDK, you may be referring to the 1.17 MDK but `source.getPlayerOrException()`  or `source.sendSuccess()` are not a part of the CommandSource class in the most recent 1.16.5 MDK.